# Partner API describeSObject on Contact fails with "Instance validation error: 'urn:address' is not a valid value for soapType."

Tags: soap-api, picklist, c#, describesobject, partner-wsdl

We're trying to pull down picklist values from the **Contact** object to show on an ASP.Net page using the **Partner API**. However, we receive the following error when the **describeSObject** call is made.

> "Instance validation error: 'urn:address' is not a valid value for soapType."

It appears that the API can not handle objects with compound fields such as address.

Here is a snippet of the code which we are using.

```
public sforce.DescribeSObjectResult[] getTableOfPickListValues(string fieldName, string[] objectName)
{
    List<string> aList = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        binding.QueryOptionsValue = new sforce.QueryOptions();
        binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSize = 500;
        binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSizeSpecified = true;
        return binding.describeSObjects(objectName);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {

    }
}
```

We've tried old and new versions of the API/WSDL and this issue appears to persist throughout.

Is this a known issue with the Salesforce partner API or are we doing something wrong? I can't seem to find anyone having reported this before...

For what it's worth, we've done this several times for custom objects so we know our code works.

Comment: Might help; https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks for the help but the issue lies in the **binding.describeSObjects(objectName);** call which we can't change. We're not specifically querying for an address field but the describeSObjects bring back all field definitions.

Comment: Can you add filter in your code to skip this field.

Comment: @TusharSharma No  we can't unfortunately. **binding.describeSObjects(objectName);** is a method generated by the Salesforce WSDL. We can't edit what it's doing. This is why I think it's a bug in the Salesforce Partner API.

Comment: @TusharSharma The error occurs before anything is returned so filtering anything is impossible.

Comment: How are you generating your binding? I've found it a little easier to use `svcutil.exe` or `wsdl.exe` via command line as opposed to adding a "web reference" in Visual Studio.

Comment: @dana We add a web service reference to the project in Visual Studio. I can't really see why using an executable would be any different as I expect that is all Visual Studio uses, but I'll give it a go. Have you found that describeSObjects works when parsing the WSDL in this way?

Comment: I have definitely been able to load picklists from the SOAP API/Partner WSDL using describeSObject/describeSObjects, although I can't seem to remember which method. I'll see if I can find some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are doing a `describeSObjects` for **Contact** and there is a problem with `urn:address` coming back in the response.

Firstly, while you might be changing the WSDL for each API version, make sure that the endpoint API version matches. [The namespace for the soapType enumerations location and address were changed between v34.0 and v35.0](http://www.fishofprey.com/2015/09/salesforce-winter-16-breaking-soap.html#bonus) (See also - [Salesforce winter 16 breaking the partner wsdl changes related to tns and uns namespace conflict](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/111129/102)). An API version mismatch could certainly produce unexpected results.

Next up I'd look at the raw SOAP response coming back from the Partner API. I use SOUP UI to test this sort of directly request.

## Request:

URL: https://mydomain-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/43.0/00D7F0000000001

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00D7F0000000001!AR_not_a_real_session_id_ySaEz_JEf1jRuJcPl7KJAT0</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:describeSObjects>
         <urn:sObjectType>Contact</urn:sObjectType>
      </urn:describeSObjects>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

## Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <LimitInfoHeader>
         <limitInfo>
            <current>8</current>
            <limit>15000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
         </limitInfo>
      </LimitInfoHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <describeSObjectsResponse>
         <result>
            <activateable>false</activateable>
            <!-- ... --> 
            <fields>
               <!-- ... --> 
               <label>Other Address</label>
                <!-- ... --> 
               <name>OtherAddress</name>
               <!-- ... --> 
               <soapType>tns:address</soapType>
               <!-- ... --> 
            </fields>
            <!-- ... --> 
            <fields>
               <!-- ... --> 
               <label>Mailing Address</label>
               <!-- ... --> 
               <name>MailingAddress</name>
               <!-- ... --> 
               <soapType>tns:address</soapType>
               <!-- ... --> 
            </fields>
            <!-- ... --> 
            <keyPrefix>003</keyPrefix>
            <label>Contact</label>
            <labelPlural>Contacts</labelPlural>
            <!-- ... --> 
         </result>
      </describeSObjectsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So that seems fine for a v43.0 Partner API call where I'd expect the namespace to be tns (urn:partner.soap.sforce.com).

Check your generated C# proxy code. I have the following:

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com")]
    public enum fieldType {
        @string,            
        // ...            
        location,           
        address,
        anyType,
        complexvalue,
    }
```

and

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com")]
    public enum soapType {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("tns:ID")]
        tnsID,
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("xsd:base64Binary")]
        xsdbase64Binary,
        //...
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("tns:location")]
        tnslocation,
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("tns:address")]
        tnsaddress,
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("xsd:anyType")]
        xsdanyType,
        //...
    }
```

Note how address has the expected tns namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I can't believe my stupidity but as you suggested we were updating the WSDL but using an old API number. We specifically set the URL, so we can easily switch between sandbox and live, instead of using the default. I'm surprised none of us spotted it over here - we were obviously on the ball yesterday! Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new console app with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SforcePartner
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SforceService sforce = new SforceService();
            sforce.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginUrl"];
            LoginResult loginResult = sforce.login(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);

            sforce.Url = loginResult.serverUrl;
            sforce.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader { sessionId = loginResult.sessionId };
            DescribeSObjectResult[] describeSObjectResults = sforce.describeSObjects(new[] { "Account" });

            Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} fields",
                    describeSObjectResults[0].name,
                    describeSObjectResults[0].fields.Length
                );
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Copy SforceService.wsdl to your project folder. Open the VS Command Prompt as follow:

```
Start -> Visual Studio 2017 -> Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017
```

Run `cd` to change to the project folder and build the Soap proxy as follows:

```
wsdl SforceService.wsdl /namespace:SforcePartner
```

Open the generated SforceService.cs in a text editor. Find `ListViewRecordColumn[][]` and replace it with `ListViewRecordColumn[]`. Now add SforceService.cs to your project.

Comment: Thank you for your response Dana, I really appreciate the help. It turns out we were updating the WSDL but not the API number. I can't believe it, we had three developers looking at it at one point! It's good to know about parsing the WSDL through WSDL.exe, it's not something I've used before but could see myself doing so in the future.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) I think we may have something in place that extracts the version number from the generated proxy for this very reason. We can switch between the test.salesforce.com and login.salesforce.com domain using the extracted version number.